# Action when click on dynamic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Scenario**

I have the following dynamic checkboxes based on MySQL database

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $srNumber = $result['srNumber'];
    $oaName = $result['oaName'];
    echo '
            <td><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="'.$oaName.'"></td>
            <td>'.$oaName.'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

I have the following jQuery codes to take an action once user clicked on any of those check boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkBoxes").onclick(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Problem

But I am not getting any alert when user click on the check box. Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a method called `onclick`

Comment: However it does have a [`click` method](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: It also has a method called `on` which takes the string `'click'` as first argument

Comment: @Dharman Oh okay!! I was using brackets as my text editor and it is not listing click as a method. Instead it shows onClick. That is why I used that. Now I got it working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use click method instead of onclick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".checkBoxes").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                alert('checked');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding these checkbox this means when you register the jQuery event these checkbox doesn't exist yet.

Make a function to declare/attach 'click' event to these checkbox immediately after they appear on the page.

Comment: Could you give me an example? And why need to do that? Because even without that, it is working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is working fine" I thought it's not?
So the idea is to have a function like
function declare(){
   $(".checkBoxes").click...
}
And then if you load some data on the page let's say with ajax. Immediately after you load your checkboxes you have to call declare() to register the same event to the newly created checkboxes

Comment: oh okay...you mean change the .onClick to .click event. Yes. I did that way based on some other comments given by other users and that is why it is working fine now